# Control another application in android

Tags: android

I want to make an application (A) that starts another application (B).
Then, I want A to send some text to a textbox in B, and click on a button in B.
The B application does not belong to me, so I don't have the source code for it.
Is this possible in android?

Comment: Yes, sort of. There is a way to create your application so that it acts like a Overlay over other applications. I've seen many apps do this, like Screen Filter, Flux, Android Game Cheat applications. I'm not sure how this can be achieved, but it should give you a direction to research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent, it's work

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: This code is used to load another app. How about click on a button and send text to a textfield?

Comment: you can use bundle send text and in another app get text

Comment: Can you say more clearly? The another app does not belong to me. I cannot view or change its source code.

Comment: if you cannot view source code how can you make sure your message has been send to another app success...

Comment: I want to do something like login to facebook. Send ID and password to facebook app. And click on Login button. Is this possible? We cannot change anything on the facebook app. If the text was sent successfully, we could see on the screen.